# Bounds of $\oint_{\partial R}\left((x^2-2xy)dx+(x^2y+3)dy\right)=\iint_{R}\left(2xy+2x\right)dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm just having some trouble figuring out the bounds and boundary of the following integral. Question as follows:

Evaluate $$\oint(x^2-2xy)dx+(x^2y+3)dy$$ around the boundary of the region contained by $y^2=8x$ and $x=2$.

Obviously I apply Green's Theorem to get $$\oint_{\partial R}\left((x^2-2xy)dx+(x^2y+3)dy\right)=\iint_{R}\left(2xy+2x\right)dxdy$$ and now my only problem is finding the bounds for the integral on the right. I think the bounds should be $\frac{1}{8}y^2<x<2$ and $-4<y<4$,$$\int_{-4}^{4}\int_{\frac{1}{8}y^2}^{2}\left(2xy+2x\right)dxdy=32$$ but the answers give $\frac{128}{15}$. Are my bounds wrong? As far as I can tell my arithmetic isn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is fine.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-4}^4\int_{\frac18y^2}^2(2xy+2x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_{-4}^4\int_{\frac18y^2}^22(y+1)x\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-4}^42(y+1)\left(2-\frac1{128}y^4\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-4}^42\left(2-\frac1{128}y^4\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=32-\frac{32}{5}\\
&=\frac{128}{5}
\end{align}
$$
In the third equation, we dropped the odd powers of $y$ since they integrate to $0$ over a symmetric region.

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is correctly set up and their answer is correct. Note that the integral $\iint_R 2xy\,dA =0$ by symmetry. You expect $1/5$ to show up because you have $\int y^4\,dy$.